# Python - match dog breed by similar traits

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to write a Python function that takes in dictionary of dog breeds with a `set` of attributes. The function takes one argument, a string `breed` which exists in the dictionary. Task is to output a list of breeds which have similar attributes to the original breed input.

If one breed has more adjectives in common with the original breed than any other, return a set containing only this breed. If more than one breed has the same number of adjectives in common with the original breed, return a set of these breeds.

I'm receiving `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'` and I'm not sure why based on the code below. My understanding is that `breed` serves as a string which is not comparable to a dict key. Any help would be awesome.

```
def find_similar_dogs(breed):
    dog_match = []
    for k, v in dogs.items(): 
        if breed in dogs.keys():
            if breed.values() == v:
                dog_match.append(k)
    return dog_match
```

Comment: `breed` is evidently a string, which doesn't have `values` method. Did you mean to call `values` on `dogs`? What was your intent? Afaik, the only common type that has a `values` method are dictionaries.

Comment: @Carcigenicate intent was to 1) check that breed exists as a key, 2) if it exists, check that the values of the breed match values of whatever other breeds exist in the dictionary, 3) append those other breeds to my empty list, 4) return the new list

Comment: You need to pass the breed dict to the function to access the breed attributes using `breeddict[breed]`. Then you can check if any of the attributes match by looping.

Comment: You should probably read through the Dictionaries section here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: @user55449 yeah thanks

Comment: @xthestreams can you explain a little more? my function is supposed to automatically load the dictionary hence why it's not passed. i thought at that point all i had to do was loop.